# jQuery - animate not working right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have this code :

```
function move() {

    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
         var x = e.pageX;
        $('.linkHover').animate({'right': '=' + x + 'px'}, 'slow'); 
   }); 


    }
```

and the HTML is :

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <ul class="linksColl">
        <li><a href="#"><img onmouseover="move()" src="images/links/communicate.png" alt="" width="175" height="78" border="0" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img onmouseover="move()" src="images/links/library.png" alt="" width="125" height="79" border="0" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img onmouseover="move()" src="images/links/memory.png" alt="" width="176" height="78" border="0" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img onmouseover="move()" src="images/links/discussions.png" alt="" width="137" height="78" border="0" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img onmouseover="move()" src="images/links/about.png" alt="" width="126" height="78" border="0" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php"><img onmouseover="move()" src="images/links/articles.png" alt="" width="125" height="78" border="0" /></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="linkHover"></div>
</div>
```

I want to change the position for DIV with class linkHover when mouse over header links but it's not working.

How I can let the linkHover DIV follow mouse cursor when become on linksColl DIV?

NOTE : I want to follow only horizontal not vertical

Comment: You will need to ensure that `linkhover` is `absolute` or `relative` as well, for the `right` parameter to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SzamDev,

Try this JS

```
function move() {    
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        var x = e.pageX;
        $('.linkHover').animate({right:x}, 'slow'); 
    }); 
}
```

also, if I understand you right, I did something very similar. Try plotting the X co-ord for each LI, then adding to an array, With the mouse over, set a JS call with an index of the li you wish to animate to. This worked perfectly for me.

```
var dotLocations = [0, 55, 170, 290, 410];
    function showFeature(a) {
        $("#featureDot").animate({
            left: dotLocations[a]
        }, 150, function () { /* animation complete */ });
    }
```

In this example the featureDot was a div with a small red dot in it, when "showFeature" was called the dot moved to be located under the li/button I clicked/hovered.

Hope this helps,

Chris.

Answer (score 1):

Animate taks a number, you can leave out the `px`

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
   var x = e.pageX;
   $('.linkHover').animate({'right': x}, 'slow'); 
});
```

It appears you want to set the `right` value to `x` so using `=` is invalid and causes your error.

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/CjHck/1/).**

Answer (score 0):

Change a line :

```
$('.linkHover').animate({'right': '=' + x + 'px'}, 'slow');
```

to

```
$('.linkHover').animate({'right': x}, 'slow');
```

and make sure you've used position of class `linkHover` `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed` 
and good luck